# Lodash filter need to get exact match, which has dynamic child node

Tags: javascript, lodash

When trying to filter array which has dynamic children node using Lodash. I was getting second level child node, but i need to filter the child node, which can be dynamically available. I am able to get to the second level, but dynamic looping not hapenning. Can u please help in looping and filter the exact child node in array using Lodash. Please find the coding done so far

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
var treeData = [{
                "id": 1,
                "title": "Test1",
                "type": [{
                    "name": "1.1",
                    "present": false
                }, {
                    "name": "1.2",
                    "present": true
                }, {
                    "name": "1.3",
                    "present": false
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 2,
                "title": "Test2",
                "type": [{
                    "name": "2.1",
                    "present": false
                }, {
                    "name": "2.2",
                    "present": true
                }, {
                    "name": "3.3",
                    "present": false
                }]
            }, {
                "id": 3,
                "title": "Test3",
                "type": [{
                    "name": "3.1",
                    "present": false,
                    "type": [{
                        "name": "3.1.1",
                        "present":false
                    }, {
                        "name": "3.1.2",
                        "present":true
                    }, {
                        "name": "3.1.3",
                        "present":false
                    }, ]
                }, {
                    "name": "3.2",
                    "present": true
                }, {
                    "name": "3.3",
                    "present": true
                }]
            }];

var result = _(treeData)
  .filter({
    type: [{ name: '3.3' }]
  })
  .map(({ type, ...o }) => ({
    ...o,
    type: _.filter(type, { name: '3.3' })
  }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

In the above example i could able to get name:3.3.. But could not able to get filter node name: "3.1.3". Can anyone please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Once I wrote following logic to find any node in a nested object.
This also works for your situation.

```js
var treeData = [{ "id": 1, "title": "Test1", "type": [{ "name": "1.1", "present": false }, { "name": "1.2", "present": true }, { "name": "1.3", "present": false }] }, { "id": 2, "title": "Test2", "type": [{ "name": "2.1", "present": false }, { "name": "2.2", "present": true }, { "name": "3.3", "present": false }] }, { "id": 3, "title": "Test3", "type": [{ "name": "3.1", "present": false, "type": [{ "name": "3.1.1", "present":false }, { "name": "3.1.2", "present":true }, { "name": "3.1.3", "present":false }, ] }, { "name": "3.2", "present": true }, { "name": "3.3", "present": true }] }];

function findByName(data, name) {

    var object;
    data.some(function f(a) {
        if (a.name == name) {
            object = a;
            return true;
        }

        _.each(Object.keys(a), function (value, key) {
            // loops through json objects in waypath
            if (!_.isEmpty(object)) {
                return false; // stop once we get the user
            }
            if (isNaN(value)) {
                // only data with string keys need to iterate more
                // when there is an array with elements
                if (Array.isArray(a[value]) && a[value].length != 0) {
                    a[value].some(f); // recursion (Didn't use return because we are in loop)
                } else if (!_.isEmpty(a[value])) {
                    // when there is an object within object
                    _.each(Object.keys(a[value]), function (val, key2) {
                        if (Array.isArray(a[value][val]) && a[value][val].length != 0) {
                            a[value][val].some(f); // recursion
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

    return object;
}

console.log("Search 3.3 :: ", findByName(treeData, "3.3"));

console.log("Search 3.1.3 :: ", findByName(treeData, "3.1.3"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```